# Override field labels in custom objects using Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api

How can I override field labels in custom object using the Metadata API ?

Comment: Why don't you just change it in the UI?

Comment: Yes, I can do it in UI but my custom object contains 90-100 fields. It'll take lots of time to do it manually  . Moreover, I've 10-15 such objects.

Comment: @Abhay - So you want to over**write** not over**ride** the labels using the metadata API? What have you tried so far, where are you stuck. Take a peek at [Ask]

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to see the [CustomObjectTranslation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customobjecttranslation.htm) entry for details, but basically you export the current data, modify your xml files, then deploy the changes using ant or your preferred deployment tool.